# AWS: How to reproduce NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need help with someone familiar with AWS and web servers. Currently I'm walking through this tutorial trying to get started with NodeJS and AWS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html

I'm trying to figure out how to essentially do a "git clone" of a traditional project but do whatever equivalent that is for an AWS project (ex: If I wanted to work on my existing AWS project on a different machine)

I read some EB CLI documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html). I tried the "eb clone env-name". However, this actually created a separate environment on AWS within my application, which isn't what I wanted. It also only added a .gitignore and a .elasticbeanstalk folder to my directory, none of my source code for my AWS application.

I'm confused on what the standard process is for working with AWS projects. Particularly, how can I start working on my existing AWS project from another machine? (Is there anyway to pull my source code from AWS project?) Is there anyway I can view my code on AWS?

*Side note:* In the past I worked with Google Apps Scripts on the cloud, which used Clasp CLI for pushing and pulling code to the cloud. This was very intuitive because it was literally `clasp pull` to pull code from cloud and `clasp push` to push code to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk isn't a code repo. It's a way to host applications in a simplified way, without having to configure the compute resources. Compare this to something like EC2 where all the networking and web server configuration is manual.

You can still use git to manage your source code, and there's [git CLI integration with Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit//dg/eb3-cli-git.html) too. Once you've got your source code working, you [bundle it up into a .zip file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/deploying-with-elastic-beanstalk.html) and upload it to EB. You can also use AWS CodeBuild to watch git repos, build source code into bundles, and automatically deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk.

If you are looking for a way to host source code on AWS, [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) is the managed git solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the Amplify Framework by AWS: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ – here's a walkthrough that will get you were you are heading faster – sure, it mentions teams but, the result can be applied to single developers too: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/multienv?sdk=js

Since you mentioned "view my code on AWS", you should have a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/ – this will walk you through setting up an account, repos and working with your code on the cloud.

Good luck!